# Perform async operations with Promise.all issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am new to nodejs and for me Promise seems to be a bit difficult to understand. I have a requirement where I have an array of objects (assume large data from database). I need to go through each data and perform two async operations(database operation) parallely for that particular data.

Here is the sample snippet attached.

```
const data = [
 {
     "id": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 2
 },
 {
     "id": 3
 },
 {
     "id": 4
 },
 {
     "id": 5
 }
];


(async () =>  {
    
    const first = async(id) => {
      // db operation  
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("first", id);
        resolve();
      }, 100 * Math.random()));
    };
    
    const second = async(id) => {
        // db operation
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("second", id);
        resolve();
      }, 100 * Math.random()));
    };
    
    const promiseResp = data.map(async(d) => {
        await first(d.id);
        await second(d.id);
    });
    
    await Promise.all(promiseResp);
})();
```

Response Getting:

```
first 5
first 3
second 5
first 4
first 2
first 1
second 3
second 2
second 4
second 1
```

I am expecting the code be run parallel for the same data. But the response is not giving the way I am expecting. My expectation is for the same id, perform both first & second async operations parallely and provide output before moving to next object. How can we achieve this?

Can somebody let me know where I am missing? Any help would be really appreciated?

**Edit**: Also how can we perform parallel operations of all the data?

Comment: You're explicitly doing `await first(d.id); await second(d.id);`, which runs the two functions sequentially per id.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry i didnt get your point. Please come again?

Answer (score 0):

To run `first` and `second` in parallel, you wouldn't use `await` but rather

```
const promises = data.map(d =>
    Promise.all([
        first(d.id),
        second(d.id),
    ])
);
await Promise.all(promises);
```

> provide output before moving to next object

For that, you must not use `data.map` but a sequential loop that `await`s the result per object:

```
for (const d of data) {
    await Promise.all([
        first(d.id),
        second(d.id),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Also for running all the operations for each data parallely my code will be enough right?

Comment: In the first section can we use await before Promise.all?

Comment: @Vishnu You mean in the `map`? No `await` is necessary there as the `map` callback should return the promise created by the `Promise.all` call.